# How do I change values in a continuous thread in java fx?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

With the following code,the thread is activated on button click in the controller class. Thing is, I want to be able to change the values in he Line array, to have to anchor pane erase old lines and add new lines.This is in the controller.java after main in launched.

```
static startVal = -1,endVal = -1;
Lines L;//this is supposed to store new lines after some methods are called


//this method is called on button click and I want it to start again every time the button is clicked
public void drawPath(){
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception {
       while(true){
            int i = 0;
            while (i<5) {
                final int finalI = i;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                   public void run() {
                   anchPane.getChildren().add(L[finalI]);

                  if(startVal == -1)
                       startVal = anchPane.getChildren.size()-1;
                   else
                      endVal = anchPane.getChildren().size()-1;
                }
              });
              i++;
              Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

          //removeLines();
          anchPane.getChildren().remove(startVal,endVal);
              }

          }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();          
    }
```

Comment: Can't you add listener to `Lines` instead, so you will add/remove `anchPane` children only when lines added or removed?

Comment: Using a custom thread is probably not appropriate here.  A better choice is likely to use a [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) to perform the animation (assuming that it is an animation that you are trying to accomplish).  Also, you shouldn't do stuff such as [`anchPane.getChildren().remove(startVal,endVal);`] off the JavaFX application thread as you may encounter race conditions and crashes.

Comment: Your problem is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060204/javafx-label-will-not-continuously-update/44060397#44060397).